# How to Recover Bitnami Stack php application from windows 7

Tags: php, html, bitnami

i installed bitnami stack php application on my windows 7,
now i lost that original source application from my pen-drive.
i need to install the same application to another computer.
is there any way to recover that software from my computer.
now the installed software working correctly.

software path c:bitnami\project\

(can i copy all files and paste another Computer in same folder ?? )

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

In case you want to have the same version of the application in a different server you have different options:

1) Stop the services of the current installation, create a backup of the full installation directory by compressing that folder. In the new server, uncompress that file in the same path and run the serviceinstall.bat script to install the services.

```
serviceinstall.bat INSTALL
```

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/faq/windows-faq/#how-to-create-a-full-backup-of-a-stack

2) Ask for the installer of that specific version of the application in our community forum and we will provide you with it.

https://community.bitnami.com